# jScrollPane temporarily disable keyboard support and than re-enable it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

## Solved

I added the following lines of code to jScrollPane plugin and now I can call jScrollPane and enable/disable the Keyboard Navigation Support

```
disableKeyboard: function()
{
    removeKeyboardNav();
},
enableKeyboard: function()
{
    initKeyboardNav();
}
```

Alright, so I am using jQuery scroll pane with a custom drop-down replacer. The custom drop-down replace supports keyboard use of the up and down arrow keys, but jScrollPane already has those binds. So what I would like to do is when the drop-down is open to disable jScrollPane keyboard support? or even if I could temporarily change what keys jScrollPane is looking for would be fine.

Is this possible?

Comment: Set enableKeyboardNavigation of jScrollPane object to false to disable keyboard support

Comment: I dont want it always disabled... just well the dropdown is open...

Comment: you just have to reenable it using some code logic e.g setting it to true when drop down is closed

Comment: I added a solution to the post and to the answers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

by adding these lines to the jScrollPane plugin I can now call the plugin and tell it to enable or disable keyboard navigation.

```
disableKeyboard: function()
{
    removeKeyboardNav();
},
enableKeyboard: function()
{
    initKeyboardNav();
}
```